# Switching ListViewes visibility causes scrolling issues

Tags: android, listview, scroll, visibility

I've tried to set up two ListViewes at one place, with only one of them visible at a time. (This is set programmatically, with setVisibility(View.GONE))
After the second ListView is visible, and gone, the first one is not scrolling. I've made some tests, and figured out, that always the second ListView's onScrollListener catches the event. 
Do you have any idea how can I set it up, that always the visible ListView's onScrollListener catches the event?
I've already tried requestFocus(), but it didn't work.

Here some sinpets from the code:

```
public void toggle_services(View v) {
    if (home_services_detail.isShown()) {
        AnimationHelper.slide_up(this, home_services_detail);
        home_services_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        home_services_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AnimationHelper.slide_down(this, home_services_detail);
        home_services_detail.requestFocus();

    }
    if (mobile_services_detail.isShown()) {
        AnimationHelper.slide_up(this, mobile_services_detail);
        mobile_services_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        mobile_services_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AnimationHelper.slide_down(this, mobile_services_detail);
        home_services_detail.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="775dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- activity_info layout file -->
            <!-- Clickable title -->
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/home_services_title"

                    android:text="@string/home_services"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="toggle_services"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    style="@style/THeader"/>
            <!--content to hide/show -->
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/home_services_detail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fees_header"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            style="@style/fees_addons"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="@string/fees"
                            android:layout_weight="0.91"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/addons_header"
                            android:layout_width="360dp"
                            style="@style/fees_addons"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/addons"/>
                </LinearLayout>

              <ListView
                      android:id="@+id/homeServicesList"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                      android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                      android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                      android:divider="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_services_title"

                    android:text="@string/mobile_services"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="toggle_services"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="5.6"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    style="@style/THeader"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:maxHeight="50dp"/>
            <!--content to hide/show -->
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_services_detail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mobile_fees_header"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            style="@style/fees_addons"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="@string/fees"
                            android:layout_weight="0.91"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mobile_addons_header"
                            android:layout_width="360dp"
                            style="@style/fees_addons"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/addons"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/mobileServicesList"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                        android:divider="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I don't know why there was strange behaviour with the visibility altering, so after all I made a work around.
In the code, where there was previously the visibility altering, now I am removing the layout from the parent that should not be on screen and add the layout that should be visible. Now both ListViews works perfectly. I think it's a little bit slower than the visibility setting, but it's working.
It was necessary to always show on the screen the two title (mobile_services_title and home_services_title), that's the reason to set the layout parameters programmatically.

The toggle function:

```
 public void toggle_services(View v){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams bigWieght=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 11f);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams smallWieght=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
        if(isHomeVisible){
            AnimationHelper.slide_up(this, home_services_detail);
            homeServicesLinearLayout.removeView(home_services_detail);
homeServicesLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(bigWieght);
            mobileServicesLinearLayout.addView(mobile_services_detail);
            AnimationHelper.slide_down(this, mobile_services_detail);
            mobileServicesLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(smallWieght);
        } else {
            AnimationHelper.slide_up(this, mobile_services_detail);
            mobileServicesLinearLayout.removeView(mobile_services_detail);
            mobileServicesLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(bigWieght);
            homeServicesLinearLayout.addView(home_services_detail);
            AnimationHelper.slide_down(this, home_services_detail);
            homeServicesLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(smallWieght);
        }
        isHomeVisible=!isHomeVisible;
    }
```

And the layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="775dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- activity_info layout file -->
        <!-- Clickable title -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/homServicesLinearLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/home_services_title"

                    android:text="@string/home_services"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="toggle_services"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    style="@style/THeader"/>
            <!--content to hide/show -->
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/home_services_detail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fees_header"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            style="@style/fees_addons"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="@string/fees"
                            android:layout_weight="0.91"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/addons_header"
                            android:layout_width="360dp"
                            style="@style/fees_addons"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/addons"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/homeServicesList"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                        android:divider="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mobileServicesLinearLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="9.5">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_services_title"

                    android:text="@string/mobile_services"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="toggle_services"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="@style/THeader"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxHeight="50dp"/>
            <!--content to hide/show -->
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_services_detail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mobile_fees_header"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            style="@style/fees_addons"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="@string/fees"
                            android:layout_weight="0.91"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mobile_addons_header"
                            android:layout_width="360dp"
                            style="@style/fees_addons"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/addons"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/mobileServicesList"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                        android:divider="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```